# Use Plates PHP with dependency injection

Tags: php, templates, dependency-injection, plates

I want to use dependency injection to pass an instance of [Plates](http://platesphp.com/v3/engine/) to my controllers with PHP-DI that is integrated with my routing system [Simple Router](https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router#dependency-injection).
I've tried to inject an instance of Plates, but I get this error:

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;

use \League\Plates\Engine;
use \League\Plates\Template\Template;
use \League\Plates\Extension\Asset;

class Controller {

  public function __construct(\League\Plates\Engine $templates)
  {
    $this->templates = $templates;
  }

?>
```

> Uncaught LogicException: The template name "home" is not valid. The default directory has not been defined

How I can solve this issue? I need also to pass the assets path with the asset() method. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the help of jcHache I've managed the injection of a Plates instance inside my base controller with this DI code:

```
<?php 

// config.php
return [
  League\Plates\Engine::class => DI\create()
    ->constructor(TEMPLATE_ROOT)
    ->method('loadExtension', DI\get('League\Plates\Extension\Asset')),
  League\Plates\Extension\Asset::class => DI\create()
    ->constructor(APP_ROOT),
];
```

index.php file

```
<?php 

use Pecee\SimpleRouter\SimpleRouter;
use DI\ContainerBuilder;

$container = (new \DI\ContainerBuilder())
  ->useAutowiring(true)
  ->addDefinitions('config.php')
  ->build();

SimpleRouter::enableDependencyInjection($container);
```

This is great but I'm facing a problem and I can't find a fix for it.
I get this error that is relative to the assets loader of plates, it seems that it's instantiated more than once. I've extended my controllers with my base controller where the asset loader is instantiated, but I don't think is this the problem? Is there a fix?

> Uncaught Pecee\SimpleRouter\Exceptions\NotFoundHttpException: The template function name "asset" is already registered

Comment: You have to define the specific dependency injection for `Plates` engine instanciation (constructor with a directory view parameter) in your `PHP-DI` configuration.

Comment: @jcHache Can you show an example please? I'm using PHP-DI from few time, so i'm learning how to obtain the best from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Plates` engine factory require a view folder parameter (see [Plates doc](http://platesphp.com/v4/engine/)):

so you have to add this creation in your `PHP-DI` configuration file:

For Plates V4:

```php
// config.php
return [
    // ...
    \League\Plates\Engine::class => function(){
        return League\Plates\Engine::create('/path/to/templates', 'phtml');
    },
];
```

For Plates V3, I'll try:

```php
// config.php
return [
    // ...
    \League\Plates\Engine::class => function(){
        return new League\Plates\Engine('/path/to/templates');
    },
];
```

or

```php
// config.php
return [
    // ...
    \League\Plates\Engine::class =>  DI\create()
       ->constructor('/path/to/templates')
    ,
];
```

Design Note:

Personally, I won't use dependency injection for a template engine, I think it would be better to instantiate Plates engine  in a base controller class.

```php
namespace controllers;

use League\Plates\Engine;

abstract class BaseController 
{
    /**
     * @var \League\Plates\Engine
     */
    protected $templates;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->templates=new Engine(\TEMPLATE_ROOT);
        $this->templates->loadExtension(new \League\Plates\Extension\Asset(\APP_ROOT));
    }

    protected function renderView(string $viewname, array $variables=[])
    {
        return $this->templates->render($viewname,$variables);
    }
}
```

For a child controller using `Plates`:

```php
namespace controllers;

class MyController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->renderView('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading the docs of PHP-DI, I was thinking about configuration, but It was unclear to me how to proceed. I'm using plates 3, your example is for the last version, but i assume it will work wiath a small modification

Comment: I've tried but got this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method League\Plates\Engine::create()`

Comment: I updated my post for `Plates V3`, you should do the same to indicate your versions (Plates, PHP-DI...)

Comment: I need to do the same also for the `assets` loader extension right? Can I call also a method with the container?

Comment: Yes, you can chain your calls: `DI\create()->constructor('/path/to/templates')->method('methodName', 'methodParameters')`

Comment: >I think it would be better to instantiate Plates engine in a base controller class 
You mean that I can instantiate plates inside the constructor of my main `Controller` and then extend other controllers with the base controller example `class foo extends bar`? I'm having some issue with the assets loader of plates if I load it inside every controller, so your suggestion sounds good

Comment: I've followed your suggestion but I always get this error `Uncaught Pecee\SimpleRouter\Exceptions\NotFoundHttpException: The template function name "asset" is already registered` I've extended my controllers with the base controller but it seems that the plates `League\Plates\Extension\Asset` is already loaded. I'm confused on how to solve this problem, I've updated the question

Comment: I have no problem with your configuration, adding a route (with 1 controller using a view).
Can you update your post by adding a route example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196774/discussion-between-jchache-and-oshione).